# Joomla 3 menu active state not working

Tags: php, joomla

I have a problem with joomla 3.

I make menu using the custom template is located in the /templates/mytemplate/html/mod_menu/mainmenu.php

But when I go on any link in the menu, then the array index of "active" is always false.

For example, curent page is `http://localhost/about.html`

and in the array "active" index is empty

```
[1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 102
            [menutype] => mainmenu
            [title] => О проекте
            [alias] => about
            [note] => 
            [route] => about
            [link] => index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1
            [type] => component
            [level] => 1
            [language] => *
            [browserNav] => 0
            [access] => 1
            [params] => JRegistry Object
                (
                    [data:protected] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [show_title] => 
                            [link_titles] => 
                            [show_intro] => 
                            [info_block_position] => 
                            [show_category] => 
                            [link_category] => 
                            [show_parent_category] => 
                            [link_parent_category] => 
                            [show_author] => 
                            [link_author] => 
                            [show_create_date] => 
                            [show_modify_date] => 
                            [show_publish_date] => 
                            [show_item_navigation] => 
                            [show_vote] => 
                            [show_tags] => 
                            [show_icons] => 
                            [show_print_icon] => 
                            [show_email_icon] => 
                            [show_hits] => 
                            [show_noauth] => 
                            [urls_position] => 
                            [menu-anchor_title] => 
                            [menu-anchor_css] => 
                            [menu_image] => 
                            [menu_text] => 1
                            [page_title] => 
                            [show_page_heading] => 0
                            [page_heading] => 
                            [pageclass_sfx] => 
                            [menu-meta_description] => 
                            [menu-meta_keywords] => 
                            [robots] => 
                            [secure] => 0
                        )

                )

            [home] => 0
            [img] => 
            [template_style_id] => 0
            [component_id] => 22
            [parent_id] => 1
            [component] => com_content
            [tree] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 102
                )

            [query] => Array
                (
                    [option] => com_content
                    [view] => article
                    [id] => 1
                )

            [deeper] => 
            [shallower] => 
            [level_diff] => 0
            [parent] => 
this empty  [active] =>
            [flink] => /about.html
            [anchor_css] => 
            [anchor_title] => 
            [menu_image] => 
        )
```

Comment: Can you maybe provide the code from `/templates/mytemplate/html/mod_menu/mainmenu.php` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of the base `mod_menu` files, the active property is always set to `false` by the helper that loads the menu and instead they use their own checks to see what is active. Namely, the base `mod_menu.php` file sets these values:

```
$list       = ModMenuHelper::getList($params);
$base       = ModMenuHelper::getBase($params);
$active     = ModMenuHelper::getActive($params);
$active_id  = $active->id;
$path       = $base->tree;
```

So `active_id` will contain the id of the current menu item. Thus if you want the current menu you can check like this:

```
foreach ($list as $i => &$item) :
if ($item->id == $active_id) {
        // do something with active item
    }
    ....
}
```

`$list` is set by the main file, so that is accessible in your layout file.

You can also check for parent items above the active item in the same foreach loop with this check:

```
if (in_array($item->id, $path)) {}
```

Technically you could run the first `foreach` loop and set `$item->active` to `true` if you wanted. However, at that point you probably could just have done what you wanted with the item!

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. :)